# Any option to post-process returned value in long conditional, other than setting variables for each statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def some_method(x)
  if x == 1
   date = Date.today 
  elsif x == 5
   date = Date.today + 2
  else
   date = Date.today - 2
 end
 date + 20
end
```

For visual clarity, is it possible somehow to omit `date =` for each statement and catch whatever the returned value is from the conditional and add `20` to it?

(The code is for example purpose, my own code has 10 if-statements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def some_method(x)
  date = if x == 1
    Date.today 
  elsif x == 5
    Date.today + 2
  else
    Date.today - 2
  end
  date + 20
end
```

If you have 10 if statements it is probably better to refactor code using `case-when` like this:

```
def some_method(x)
  date = case x
    when 1; Date.today 
    when 5; Date.today + 2
    else; Date.today - 2
  end
  date + 20
end
```

Comment: 5+ for providing the `case-when` alternative.